aspnet razor pages form local-datetime not working with NodaTime LocalDateTime
I have a form with an input of type local-datetime that is expecting a Date and a Time with the following format : yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm
By default NodaTime LocalDateTime format is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss and I need to strip the seconds from it.
Here is a sample razor pages app :
Project.csproj
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2024.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.1.12" />
</ItemGroup>

CustomLocalDateTimeConverter.cs
// TypeConverterBase is coming from
// https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/main/src/NodaTime/Text/TypeConverterBase.cs
public class CustomLocalDateTimeConverter : TypeConverterBase<LocalDateTime>
{
    public CustomLocalDateTimeConverter()
      : base(LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")) { }
}

Program.cs
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(LocalDateTime),
    new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(CustomLocalDateTimeConverter)));

Index.cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public LocalDateTime Local { get; set; } = new LocalDateTime(2024, 09, 11, 12, 12);
    
    public void OnPost()
    {
            
    }
}

Index.cs.cshtml
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Local" type="datetime-local" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

With this in place, if you select a value from the local-datetime input and send the form back to the server, the LocalDateTime will be parsed with the CustomLocalDateTimeConverter.
But when you load the page, the asp-for tag helper is rendering the date like this instead of showing the default date from Index.cshtml.cs:

And the generated html code is
<form method="post">
    <input type="text"
           data-val="true"
           data-val-required="The Local field is required."
           id="Local"
           name="Local"
           value="11/09/2024 12:12:00">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="...">
</form>

The value attribute is not respecting the format, it looks like ToString() was used instead of our CustomLocalDateTimeConverter

In terms of supporting post but not get, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#model-binding-for-http-get-requests - you may need [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]. Additionally, there's this documentation about default model binding:"Route data and query string values are used only for simple types." (I'm not sure whether putting FromQuery can help with that.)

The issue is not linked to the bind property, but when the page is rendered. The TypeConverter is not used to populate the value of the input. It seems that it use ToString()

"The issue is not linked to the bind property, but when the page is rendered." I thought this was about the model binding, i.e. the value that gets parsed from the request. Is that not the case? Please make it really clear in the question, because at the moment it certainly sounds like it's a model binding question (i.e. parsing the request). In particular: "The default format the browser is using to send data back to server is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm which is not supported by default by NodaTime."

First of all thanks a lot for your help.
I rewrote the question, which should be easier to understand now.

So is the question about the generated HTML, or what happens when the form is submitted? Those are significantly different paths. (One is formatting, the other is parsing - and they're potentially configured in very different ways, I'm not sure.)

The question now is about the generated html

Okay - given that this looks like it's not what the original question was about, it would have been better to create a new question, IMO. I'll see if I can get the time to try to reproduce this in the next few days, but please bear in mind in the future that significantly changing the purpose of a question can end up being deeply frustrating for those trying to help you.

This may or may not be the best way of doing it, but it's fairly simple to specify the format used in an <input> element, using the Format property:
<input asp-for="Local" type="datetime-local" asp-format="{0:uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm}" />

Note that I expect this will still use "the current culture" instead of an invariant culture pattern, which is definitely not ideal, but is unlikely to make any difference with the above pattern. (The LocalDateTime "knows" its own calendar system, so it's not going to affect that, for example.)
You may well still need the answers from the earlier version of the question (e.g. specifying a [TypeConverter] attribute on the property) in order to make sure that the value is then parsed correctly on submission.

Thanks a lot Jon, the asp-format and the TypeConverter are making it working.
Making the TypeConverterBase public would be interesting for this use case.

In an ASP.Net Core way you could try custom Model Binder.
ModelBinder
public class TimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);

        var valueAsString = value.FirstValue;

        if (LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm").Parse(valueAsString).TryGetValue(LocalDateTime.MinIsoValue, out var localDateTime))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(localDateTime);
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

ModelBinderProvider
public class TimeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        var modelType = context.Metadata.ModelType;

        if (modelType == typeof(LocalDateTime) || modelType == typeof(LocalDateTime?))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(TimeModelBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}

Register service
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddJsonOptions(o =>
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb))
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TimeModelBinderProvider());
    });


This way the NodaTime can work with the input type datetime-local, however since it doesn't deal with seconds, it is always 00.
